# Linux POSIX Compliance list

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, posix

I'm looking for a list cross reference matrix of POSIX implemented functions for a specified linux kernel.

For example, I want to use linux kernel 2.6.0, but I would like to see the compmlete list of POSIX implemented functions for this kernel.  Where can I find this information?

Comment: Kernels don't need to implement POSIX, kernel + libs do :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linux follows the [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) as opposed to POSIX. However, LSB is mostly a superset of POSIX. You can find a list of all observed conflicts between LSB and POSIX [here](http://www.opengroup.org/personal/ajosey/tr28-07-2003.txt). I doubt something as detailed as what it seems you want exists.

Comment: I think this will be the best information I can get.  Thanks it does help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`2.6.0` is really an old kernel (there are big differences with `2.6.38`). Try using something less old.

The linux [syscalls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) man page gives you a list of system calls and in what kernel version they appears, so answers the question for syscalls. For library functions, I have no idea.

In practice, Linux seems to me quite Posix compliant... And the Posix standard also evolved.

Comment: The kernel version was really just an example.  The system that is being put together has two independant systems that are using two different versions of linux.  I think the oldest one being used at the moment is 2.6.19.

Comment: Thanks!  This is really useful.  I can cross reference any specific functions and see which POSIX standard they conform to.  This helps a lot.